# wpf control containing ComboBox and Items setter

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

with WPF I can do soemthing like this:

```
<Combobox>
    <ComboBox.Items>
        <system:Boolean>True</system:Boolean>
        <system:Boolean>False</system:Boolean>
    </ComboBox.Items>
</Combobox>
```

But I have problem with creating a custom control, which will `delegate` Items to ComboBox

When I do something like this:

```
<Combobox Items={Binding something}/>
```

I receive compilation error about Items setter (because Items have no setter).
How can I handle that? I mean, set/rewrite items from my control to combobox?

Answer (score 2):

To define the list in XAML to binding, use a ResourceDictionary.  This could be in a separate file, but below I have included it in Window.Resources:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary x:Key="boolArray">
            <sys:Boolean x:Key="true">True</sys:Boolean>
            <sys:Boolean x:Key="false">False</sys:Boolean>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
```

Then you can apply the XAML-defined array to the ItemsSource property of your ComboBox:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Values, Source={StaticResource boolArray}}"/>
```

In case it isn't clear, the sys namespace is defined as follows:

The sys namespace is defined as follows:

```
xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
```

Comment: But I would like to specify these items in xaml. Perfectly, like in my Combobox example in main post

Comment: Ok so you want to define everything in XAML?  I will update the answer right now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public class Test
{
    public string T { get; set; }
}

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    this.DataContext = new List<Test>()
    {
        new Test(){T = "1"}
    };
}

<ComboBox  ItemsSource="{Binding T}"/>
```